# create tagging schema

Tags: tags, data-analysis

There are ~50k articles which needs to be analyzed and a tag schema dictionary needs to be created post, which becomes the base for the Auto Tagging feature we plan to build for the site.

Are there any tools available to tag the data and help generate a list of kind of data available in the data-set.

If not then what would be a good place to start?

Comment: What environment is this for?  What format is the data in?

Comment: This is for a blog based on wordpress i.e Linux and MySQL

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse KSK has given me the exact solution that I needed. So no spam!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a data mining tool called Weka, You can try downloading it. There are many weka videos in youtube. You can also google it there is lot of information available.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are few tools for data analysis and you can watch videos on youtube to learn one of them. 
1) Weka, KNIME- if you are good in Java then you should go for it.
2)Orange, NLTK- if you are good in python then you can choose this.
3)R-programming- if you are good in C, then you can go for it.